# VS 2012 InstallShield doesn't install my service to the machine

Tags: c#, service, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I developed a service and I wanna make installer which will install to windows 8. I used InstallShield and I created a setup.exe for this(I included primary outputs and Service.exe).
So when I run setup, I can't see my service on my services. It doesn't install my service to my system. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues when moving from visual studio 2010. 2012 proved difficult when trying to create an installer for services. Try the following, it worked for me.

http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2013/04/installing-a-windows-service-with-visual-studio-2012/